# php error : error in connection to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

I am a beginner with php and I copied this code from a tutorial :

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("example.com","username","password");
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE my_db";
 if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
     echo "Database my_db created successfully";
 }
?>
```

I got an error in my localhost:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you using any server, like wamp/xampp, etc?

Comment: Did you try `("localhost","username","password")`?

Comment: Just change: `"example.com"` to `"localhost"` and `"username"` to `"root"` and `"password"` to`""`. Also good that you watch a tutorial! Watch it until the end :D

Comment: yeh thanks :D
it has worked

Comment: How are you launching this script? From local machine to remote host? In that case you may have an error if remote connection to database is restricted. To check this just try to connect to example.com via command line mysql command

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a connection to your local mySQL Database.

By default, the parameters should be:

- Host: localhost
- Username: root
- Password:

If you haven't set any username or password, these parameters should work for you. So, change your mysqli_connect function to:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

Hope this helps.